# Merge two files with no pseudo-repetitions

Tags: linux, command-line, awk, sed

I have two text files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`  which both contain lines of words  like this:

`fare
word
word-ed
wo-ded
wor`

and

`fa-re
text
uncial
woded
wor
worded`

or something like this. By a word, I mean a succession of the letters a-z possibly with accents, together with the symbol `-`. My question is, how can I create a third file `output.txt` from linux command line (using `awk`, `sed` etc.) out of these two files which satisfies the following three conditions:

1. If the same word occurs in the two files, the third file `output.txt`  contains it exactly once.
2. If a hyphenated version (for example `fa-re` in file2.txt) of a word in on file occurs in another, then only the hyphenated version is retained in output.txt (for example, only `fa-re` is retained in our example).

Thus, output.txt should contain the following words:

`fa-re
word
word-ed
wo-ded
wor
text
uncial`

================Edit========================

I have modified the files and given the output file as well.
I will try to make sure manually that there are no differently hyphenated words (such as wod-ed and wo-ded).

Comment: Step 1 is easy -- `cat file1.txt file2.txt | uniq > output.txt`. Can you give some examples for Step 2? It's rather confusing. And can you explain why you want to do this? Keeping hyphenated versions of duplicates seems very strange.

Comment: Thank you for the step 1. From the output, I would like to remove all unhyphenated versions, but Only if a hyphenated version exists. That would suffice.

Comment: Step 2 is too complicated to achieve cleanly in sed/awk/perl at the command line. This deserves a small script.

Comment: Step 2 as I have explained is not necessary, all I want is to remove unhyphenated words if a hyphenated word exist, that is, if `fa-re` and `fare` both occur in my file, I would like to remove `fare`.

Comment: don't give us a bunch of `...`s and `something like this` - give us concrete, precise, testable input and expected output.

Comment: Edited, now the question would be clearer I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another awk:

```
!($1 in a) || $1 ~ "-" { 
    key = value = $1; gsub("-","",key); a[key] = value 
}
END { for (i in a) print a[i] }

$ awk -f npr.awk file1.txt file2.txt
text
word-ed
uncial
wor
wo-ded
word
fa-re
```

Answer (score 1):

## Awk Solution

```
!($1 in words) {
    split($1, f, "-")
    w = f[1] f[2]
    if (f[2])
        words[w] = $1
    else
        words[w]
}
END {
    for (k in words)
        if (words[k])
            print words[k]
        else
            print k
}
```

```
$ awk -f script.awk file1.txt file2.txt
wor
fa-re
text
wo-ded
uncial
word-ed
word
```

### Breakdown

```
!($1 in words) {
    ...
}
```

Only process the line if the first field doesn't already reside as a key in the array `words`.

---

```
split($1, f, "-")
```

Splits the first field into the array `f` using `-` as the delimiter.  The first and second parts of the word will reside in `f[1]` and `f[2]` respectively.  If the word is not hyphened, it will reside in its entirety inside `f[1]`.

---

```
w = f[1] f[2]
```

Assigns the dehyphened word to `w` by concatenating the first and second parts of the word.  If the word was not originally hyphened, the result will be the same since `f[2]` is empty.

---

```
if (f[2])
    words[w] = $1
else
    words[w]
```

Store the dehyphened word as a key in the `words` array.  If the word was hyphened (`f[2]` is not empty), store it as the key's value.

---

```
END {
    for (k in words)
        if (words[k])
            print words[k]
        else
            print k
}
```

After the file has been processed, iterate through the `words` array, and if the key holds a value (hyphened word), print it, otherwise print the key (non-hyphened word).

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you asked but perhaps better suited with what you need.

```
awk '{k=$1; gsub("-","",k); w[k]=$1 FS w[k]} END{for( i in w) print w[i]}'
```

this will group all words in the files by equivalence class (match without hyphen).  You can have another pass from this result to get what you desire.

```
uncial
word
woded wo-ded 
wor wor
worded word-ed
text
fa-re fare
```

The advantages are not manually checking whether there are alternative hyphenated words and see how many different instances you have for each word.
For example, this will filter out the previous list to desired output.

```
awk '{w=$1; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(match($i,/-/)!=0)w=$i; print w}'
```